# C++ array - uses only first line

Tags: c++, arrays

i have problems with the array function.. - 
i put my mac on fist line and then says me `approved` , but if is on 2st line `rejected`. my real one is B6 on end. /address down are not real../

in heder file settings >

`#define CLIENTSNUMBER 2`

`BOOL Checking2(LPCSTR MacID);`

cpp >

```
    char ClientMacs[CLIENTSNUMBER*1][18] = {
    "5A-77-77-97-87-B7",
    "5A-77-77-97-87-B6"
    };

BOOL Checking2(LPCSTR MacID)
{
    for(int x=0;x<CLIENTSNUMBER;x++)
    {
        if(!strcmp(MacID,ClientMacs[x])) 
             {
             MessageBoxA(NULL,MacID,"APPROVED!",MB_OK);
             return false;  
         }  else {
             MessageBoxA(NULL,MacID,"REJECTED!",MB_OK); 
             return false;
         }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Have you removed the body of your question?

Comment: I've rolled back the edits to restore the body of code. @Valtentin, you shouldn't remove the code after the question is answered; the point of Stack Overflow is to build up a repository of questions and answers, and deleting the question makes the answer useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you return from your function (breaking out of your loop) when something matches or *doesn't* match. It will never actually loop.

**Edit because it's a slow morning:**

You need to go through the entire array and look at every element for a match before declaring it's rejected:

```
BOOL Checking2(LPCSTR MacID)
{
    for(int x=0;x<CLIENTSNUMBER;x++)
    {
        if(strcmp(MacID,ClientMacs[x]) == 0) 
        {
             MessageBoxA(NULL,MacID,"APPROVED!",MB_OK);
             return false;  
        }  
    }

    MessageBoxA(NULL,MacID,"REJECTED!",MB_OK); 
    return false;
}
```

Also, do you really mean to return `false` in both cases? I would assume if you find a match it should return `true`